# BCP Command gives different output in SQL Server 2005 compared to 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp, sqlcmd

I have executed two identical bcp commands on two different setups with the same data.

**Machine A** = Windows Vista machine which is running SQL Server 2008

**Machine B** = Windows Server 2003 machine running SQL Server 2005

The output text file of the bcp command is different! For a start, **Machine B** does not add column names to the beginning of the text file and it seems to get line breaks wrong. Each row should be separated by line breaks instead it seems as if its putting in line breaks after two fields?!

The bcp command is this:

```
bcp DBn_Mitor..TI40 out C:\prepTI4O.txt -c -T -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -S SQLServer01 -E
```

What is going on here? What is different in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 that will make bcp work differently?

Comment: Dumb questoin, are you sure the tables have exactly the same schema?  Does the data differ at all (newlines maybe)?

Comment: @C.Ross - Hi, yes I am very sure as I export the same table from the same Access Database - I have checked the number of columns, rows just as a quick test of my sanity and its exactly the same!

Comment: @abs: I think C.Ross means SQL Server table definition, collation etc
What has MS Access got to do with bcp?

Comment: @Gbn, I import from MS Access to SQL Server as views. I then export that out using BCP.

Comment: I think the problem is how each field is setup in access, even though they are exactly the same tables. I have just noticed in one of my fields the date is in a different format! Maybe I need a way to say make all fields text when I have created the view. Is this possible, maybe this should be another quesiton...

Comment: Can you use bcp on machine A to extract data on machine B? And vice versa. It may narrow down whether the server data is different or the bcp behavior is different. My guess is that it's something on the server data. 
Also, comparing results of sp_help TI40 on Machines A and B would be helpful. Make sure they're character by character identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCP is a SQL tool ,2008 does come with a different version I believe. I think if you are using BCP to export/import between versions you should use RAW and not Native.

From Access to SQL, the best option is to use a format file - details of this can be found on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Has the server ever been upgraded, or have other DBMS tools installed? AKA, are you running the correct bcp.exe?

I've seen this before where the "bcp.exe" found when looking in the %PATH% variable is not the one you expect to run...